# How to assign types to destructured variables in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

If I wanted to assign different types to each of the destructured parameters being passed into a function, instead of a uniform type, what should the format be?

For example, if I wanted all three variables to be string, the it would be the following format:

```js
const Auth = ({ history, match, path }: string) => {
    //content
}
```

But, what if I wanted the first one to be an object, second a string, and a third to be an array?

Comment: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript. Searching for your exact title brought that up as the first result. Sometimes (almost always) searching is faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to type the object being destructured, fully.

```
const Auth = ({ history, match, path }: {
  history: string,
  match: string,
  path: string
}) => {
    //content
}
```

Typescript will then lookup the types of those properties and then correctly infer the proper types.

---

Some variations.

Make a discrete type for the object being destructured. (I use this pattern for react props quite a bit):

```
interface AuthInfo {
  history: string,
  match: string,
  path: string
}

const Auth = ({ history, match, path }: AuthInfo) => {
    //content
}
```

Or less strongly typed:

```
const Auth = ({ history, match, path }: { [key: string]: string }) => {
    //content
}
```

Different types for different keys:

```
const Foo = ({ a, b }: { a: string, b: number[] }) => {
    //content
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare the type of the whole object being passed as the argument to `Auth`, i.e.

```js
const Auth = ({ match, path }: {match: string, path: string[]}) => {
}
```

Everything to the right of `:` is the type of the parameter. Unfortunately this can get pretty verbose and repetitive.

Note that you have to do this as well in your initial code - your example function accepts a **single parameter of type string** and tries to de-structure it. This won't compile, string has no properties named `path` and `history` (it does have a method named `match` so that one will work, but probably isn't what you intended)

Answer (score -3):

In typescript, it is better use this syntax:

```
const Auth = ({ history:object, match:string, path :string}) =>
  { // function contents
  }
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. This is object destructuring with renaming; it is passed through untouched by the TS compiler. Also discussed in the link I commented on, but this is just standard ES6 syntax.